# Verb or phrasal verb that means to provide information on a website

Tags: word-choice, word-request

what would be the appropriate and most common verb or phrasal verb to say that someone entered/ has to enter their information on a website? (address, phone number, name, credit card number,etc)
I've done some research and found these options so far:

I've *filled out/filled* in my information on the website.

You have to *key in* your information on the website before placing the order.

You have to *type in* all your information on the website before proceeding to checkout.

Are they correct?

Comment: What's wrong with 'entered', which is what I normally say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many equally valid usages.

- "Provide" is direct and has the benefit of not being tied to a particular form of input.
- As noted, "enter" is also nice
- "Fill out/in" makes sense when there is a form, especially with more than one or two inputs.
- "Key in" and "type in" would be understood, but I would discourage them on a website for accessibility reasons. Not every user uses a keyboard, and there are other input technologies. "Key in" is more associated with devices with a more limited keypad, like credit card readers.
- Similarly, "I have typed my information in" puts a strange emphasis on how you're entering the data.

Answer (score 4):

I would say ***enter your information/personal details***. Here are some instances:

> - Simply *enter your information* in the boxes below George, and wait to be sent your bottle of the chicken sunscreen. ([Huffington Post](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/keep-from-getting-too-crispy-with-kfcs-fried-chicken-scented-sunscreen_n_57bb09f0e4b00d9c3a18a488))
> - Please *enter your* university's *details* via our dedicated website. ([The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2011/dec/16/cribsheet-primary-school-tables))
> - Please *Enter Your Information* to Register to the Product Education Seminar ([wellnesscenter.net](https://www.wellnesscenter.net/please-enter-your-information-to-register-to-the-product-education-seminar/))

Answer (score 1):

- I have filled out the form on the website.
  OR
- I have filled in the form on the website.
  OR
- I have typed my information into the form.

Please note the expressions: to fill out a form, to fill in a form, type information into a form.

To key in data or information into some program, etc. = used more in IT contexts, not consumer purchasing online.